# WPF DataGrid validation when bound to a DataView

Tags: wpf, validation, wpfdatagrid, dataview

I am attempting to validate input on a `DataGrid` which is populated by a `DataView` (e.g. `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataView`). However, all the WPF DataGrid validation examples I have seen assume that the `DataGrid` source is a C# class. I can't figure out how to hook up a single cell (i.e. a column) to a code-behind validation.  Can someone give an example or point me to one?

Comment: The examples you saw are probably the best way forward; are you sure you don't want to go that way? WPF in its entirety is pretty much geared toward that style, and going against it is usually harder.

Comment: I am nonplussed that it is trivial to assign a DataView as the data source for a DataGrid, yet it really is difficult to perform validation in that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more research, and what I was basically missing was that I can specify the column name with the `Path` attribute of a `Binding` (or even use the column ordinal in brackets, *e.g.* `Path="[0]"`). After that realization, everything is basically the same as using a class property. So a typical `DataGrid` column definition I use follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Regular" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ValidationErrorStyleBoxRA}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ValidationErrorStyleBlockRA}" Width="60">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="HourlyRate" StringFormat="F3" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:HourlyRatesAmountValidate ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some quick tests; I think the main impediment to really doing it manually is that the DataGridCell doesn't create any bindings for its content when assigning directly a DataView for display. However, if you're willing to jump through the hoops of assigning custom  `DataGridTemplateColumn`s when creating the DataGrid, you can access the bindings on, say, the TextBox instances inside the template, and set custom validation errors on them.

Well actually, either this or override the default style of the textboxes generated by the DataGrid; you see, the default textbox style doesn't have any borders or anything, so setting a validation error on it doesn't have any effect. Making it into a normal textbox with DataTemplate or overriding its style would enable you to actually make something visible as an effect of setting the validation error.

However you'll need to do some research by yourself; I did a quick prototype and it works, but I can't create the binding correctly in the DataTemplate (either I forgot all the WPF I knew since I worked with it last, or I only know how to work with proper bindings :)). If you get somewhere with that it's easier going forward:

Somehow get access to a BindingExpression; what I did was attach a handler to the LostFocus event and checking if what lost focus was a textbox that was inside a DataGridCell; if so, I simply mark that binding as invalid (with `t` representing a TextBox instance):

```
var x = t.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

Validation.MarkInvalid(x, new ValidationError(new ExceptionValidationRule(), x.ParentBinding, "error", new Exception("error")));
```

I must confess I'm not sure anymore what each argument's role is in the ValidationError constructor is (I think the exception message is displayed by default in the validation tooltip? Or is it the error content?), but I'm sure you can figure it out. Now if you don't mind, I think I'll take a break... like I said, it's not easy going against the flow :)